# How to access dynamic content in list from setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

In javascript, On `$(document).ready(function()` I have a function `updateRecordTime()` run to update dates in list items (with nested divs), and I have a `setInterval()` run that function every 30 seconds to update, but after a dynamically add list items via ajax they are not updated also. I have the function running on a static element to look at an Unordered List for its list items but its not working and I can't figure it out.

```
  updateRecordTime = function () {
      $('#record-lister > li').each(function (index) {
          var record_time = $(this).find('.record-time');
          date = moment(new Date(record_time.attr('data-date')));
          update = function () {
              record_time.html('Record - ' + date.fromNow() + ' <i class="icon-time"></i>');
          };
          update();
      });
  }

  updateRecordTime();
  setInterval(updaterecordTime, 30000);
```

The html (relevant code) is as follows

```
<ul id="record-lister">
    <li>
         <div class="record-time" data-date="'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp).'">
              gets replaced with moment time....                                                            
         </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="record-time" data-date="'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp).'">
              gets replaced with moment time....                                                            
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If I call the function after a successful ajax call, it's updated once, but the loop doesn't find it, I'm aware `setInterval()` will loop the original list items but how can I get it to also find the dynamically added ones too?

Comment: It should find new LIs. You have a typo in your posted script: `setInterval(updaterecordTime, 30000);` must be: `setInterval(updateRecordTime, 30000);`.

Comment: the Typo is cut and paste error on my part ;), it's weird it just doesn't update the new ones :S

Comment: So what are you doing inside update() function?

Comment: `$('#record-lister > li')` will find all the li elements inside `#record-lister` each time `updateRecordTime()` runs, including dynamically created li elements. Are you sure your dynamically added items are going inside `#record-lister`? Also, what's the point of defining `update()` inside the `.each()` loop and then calling it immediately? Couldn't you just put the line inside that function directly in the `.each()`?

Comment: As I'm learning, the code in the loop was not originally in a loop so I will correct that ;)

Comment: @nnnnnn it run the new dynamic ones once and once only, it's a weird issue I know but I don't know how to find why. The dynamic list items are added fine (But I will clearly check that in case ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [A.Wolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) said, your code should find the newly inserted li tags.

1. Make sure you correctly populate the ul tag having id="record-lister". You can inspect the html code added dynamically to make sure of this.
2. Watch js errors from your browser console so that the code doesn't break at some point. I recommend you Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools.
3. When calling setInterval(funcName, interval), you must be aware that funcName is a pointer to your function and you must pay attention to function scopes. Calling setInterval("funcName()", interval) will call funcName from the global scope ( i.e. window.funcName ).

Based on the code given by you here, those are my advices, and it should work just fine assuming that adding html code via ajax works good.

Comment: Turns out the add record html was missing the data-date attribute, whereas the loop loading the records on page load was fine, cheers @eAbi